# Rails ActiveRecord Ignoring Params and Saving Nil Data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is stumping me; For some reason the db is saving the record with nil fields instead of my params.  Can anyone help me understand why ActiveRecord isn't using my params?

db migration:

```
class CreateRoutes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :routes do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string  :start_address
      t.string  :end_address
      t.text    :waypoints
      t.text    :schedule
      t.integer :duration

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :routes, :user_id
  end
end
```

route.rb:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :start_address, :end_address, :waypoints, :schedule, :duration
  belongs_to :user
  #serialize :waypoints, :schedule

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :start_address, presence: true
  validates :end_address, presence: true
  validates :schedule, presence: true
  validates :duration, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }

end
```

routes_controller.rb:

```
class RoutesController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    logger.debug "\n\n*** #{params[:route]} ***"

    @route = current_user.routes.build(params[:route])

    logger.debug "*** The route is #{@route.inspect} ***\n\n"

    if @route.save
      flash[:success] = "Route saved!"
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

logger output:

```
*** {"start_address"=>"123 Sample St.", "end_address"=>"321 Elpmas St.", "waypoints"=>"None", "schedule"=>"Mondays", "duration"=>"15"} ***
*** The route is #<Route id: nil, user_id: 1, start_address: nil, end_address: nil, waypoints: nil, schedule: nil, duration: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> ***
```

Comment: Why are you defining attr_accessors for the DB properties?

Comment: I'd like to make this data readable/writable from other parts of my code.  Attr_accessor seemed easier than writing specific read/write methods.  I have no idea if this is idiomatic to rails; a lot of my style is based on Hartl's tutorial.

Comment: DB properties already have accessors, provided by ActiveRecord. It's likely you're overwriting them.

Comment: Hot damn; you're right.  Commenting out just the attr_accesor line results in my params data being saved correctly.  Any idea why Hartl explicitly calls out db fields with attr_accessor in his tutorial?  Also, if you'd like to add your last comment as a solution, I'll mark it as correct.  THANK YOU!  This has had me stumped for a bit.

Comment: I don't recall seeing that in the tutorial, although I admit it's been awhile--do you have a reference/page number/link/etc? I only remember explicit accessors for virtual properties.

Comment: I believe he first describes it in the Rails 3.2 tutorial at §6.1.2.  He claims that by explicitly defining the accessible properties, this is to prevents a 'mass assignment vulnerability' allowing users to submit their own POST commands to assign sensitive properties.  While this specific model doesn't have any sensitive properties, do you have any idea why my attr_accessor is preventing ActiveRecord from saving the properties?

Comment: That's not `attr_accessor`, that's `attr_accessible`, at least in the [link I looked at](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users?version=3.2#sec:accessible_attributes).

Comment: And those four letters ('ible' vs. 'or') seem to be very important. :)  Changing my code to attr_accessible allows me to read/write to those properties while protecting the others.  I apologize that all this back-and-forth was over four characters in my code, but you did help me learn something.

Comment: It's all obvious, once we know it ;) I curse the computer every day for not having a Do What I Mean interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `attr_accessor`s will overwrite the accessors generated by `ActiveRecord`, causing them to not be persisted in the DB--they'll be like plain old Ruby properties/members instead of the meta-programmed magic of `ActiveRecord`.

DB properties (persistent properties) can have things like `attr_accessible`, though.

Comment: Thank you; my code specifies `attr_accessor` for these properties making them read-only.  Changing this to 'attr_accessible' solves my write problem (as expected.)  Thank you for the newbie fix.